# How can I convert an Indeo 5.1 format file to a more current, supported format using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I had a large series of images from a kitchen rebuild that I compiled into a time-lapse video that was very cool.

Unfortunately I used the Indeo 5.1 codec that has since been lost to history, now I need to convert that into something that can actually be read by modern video systems.

I loaded ffmpeg on laptop, but can't figure out the correct incantation to use.

Comment: Why not use Handbrake instead? It’s GUI based so no “correct incantation” is needed.

Comment: What "incantations" have you used? Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something that you are only doing once, and especially if you're unfamiliar with the command line, you'd be better off using [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/). This provides a GUI and a number of presets so you won't need to worry about the correct ffmpeg "incantation". It's a frontend for ffmpeg so you'll get the same result as using the command line.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeo#Implementations), ffmpeg has fully supported the Indeo codecs since 2011.

Basic ffmpeg syntax is

```
ffmpeg <input options> -i inputfile.avi <output options> outputfile.mp4
```

You shouldn't need any input options here, since converting from one format to another is a straightforward procedure -- ffmpeg should auto-detect what codec was used (Indeo 5) and apply the correct decoder.

In terms of output options, you can consult [the ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki#Encoding) for detail.

You can probably rely on anything you want to play your video on supporting an MP4 container with H.264 video and AAC audio. A possible command to use would be:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.avi -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -c:a aac -b:a 128k outputfile.mp4
```

If there's no audio, you can skip the audio options like this:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.avi -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 ouputfile.mp4
```

Have a look at the wiki for more detail. You can adjust the crf to trade of quality against file size, and you can adjust the preset to trade off encoding time against file size. You may also want to use the `-tune stillimage` option depending how slideshow-like your video is.